# Citing a source of a figure in a text

Tags: citations

I would like to know, if it is common (in a dissertation) to cite the source of a special figure also in the text. So for example I have the following sentence:

"Figure 1 shows the share of renewable energy in Europe for the year 2018 ."

In the text underneath Figure 1 I cite the corresponding source, like:
'Figure 1: Share of renewable energy in Europe for the year 2018 (Eurostat, 2018)'

Should the source (Eurostat, 2018) also be appended to the sentence in the text like:
"Figure 1 shows the share of renewable energy in Europe for the year 2018 (Eurostat, 2018)."

I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: If it's an original scholarly work you should be making your own figure from the source data, not using a figure that someone else made. Source should be cited in the figure/legend and should be appropriately included in the references. You may also include it in the text but it's less important there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is normally enough to cite it once. If it is clear to the reader there should be no issue. The caption is complete, with the citation. The text itself can read more naturally.

But this is just a style suggestion. Correctness and clarity are the goals.

Caveat: Some journal may have their own style guide, but you will be told of that as part of the review process. For a dissertation it is fine to say it once unless your advisor objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot Buffy for your great answer.